# Tab button messing with events

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got

`window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);`

And when I press tab it registers the first time.

But after that it really screws everything up. I suspect it changes the focus away from `window` and it goes off of the window. Like when I press it 5 times it focuses the URL bar. But I don't want that. There doesn't appear to be a way to bail out of that behavior!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to prevent the default behaviour of that key using event.preventDefault().

That being said this will not work on keyup as the default behaviour is triggered on keydown. You can either change your code, or add a second listener.

Comment: Ahh adding stopPropagation to the keydown worked.